# Ant executable attribute

Tags: bash, ant

I work with bash and Ant and I want to execute this command

```
    <exec dir="../../../path/to/"  executable="./configure">
         <arg line="--prefix=$(readlink -f ./../../../Applications/common/lg-media-server/rpmbuild/pp)"/>
    </exec>
```

It does not work .Can anyBody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Ant doesn't interpret the command line arguments like a shell do. You must first evaluate `$(readlink -f ./../../../Applications/common/lg-media-server/rpmbuild/pp)` via Ant before calling the configure.

Something like these two steps should do the work:

```
<exec executable="readlink" outputproperty="pp_path">
    <arg line="-f ./../../../Applications/common/lg-media-server/rpmbuild/pp"/>
</exec>

<exec dir="../../../path/to/"  executable="./configure">
    <arg line="--prefix=${pp_path}"/>
</exec>
```